# IE9 XMLHTTPRequest request body incomplete but readyState=4 statuscode=200

Tags: php, javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

I have an issue in IE9 where the request body of an XMLHTTPRequest is *incomplete*.

The code that handles the XMLHTTPRequest waits for readyState=4, then checks statuscode=200. It will then proceed to `JSON.parse` but that fails because the request body is *incomplete*. When I inspect the request body I can clearly see that it's cut-off at some point in the string, like in the middle of a property.

Server-side there is very little to check, it's just a matter of `echo json_encode($reply);`

I know AJAX errors can come from a wide range of sources, like: over-eager firewalls, but that would be accompanied by a proper status like (like `403`). In this case the XMLHTTPRequest response seems to think everything is fine so I don't know how to detect it. Is there another property I can check, or does IE9 perhaps cut off long response bodies?

I will continue to investigate this, but as I can't not reproduce it myself this may take a couple of days.

**Can anyone confirm these issues and perhaps point me to a solution?**

**Note:** This only seems to occur in IE9, I suppose that's because older versions don't use XMLHTTPRequest but ActiveXObject. This does not occur in Chrome or Firefox, at least: I haven't seen it.

Comment: Are you cached with a bad request?

Comment: All requests as `POST` requests, so caching is not an issue.

Comment: Are the requests taking a long time to come back? Does using a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) bring any more insight into the requests?

Comment: I can not reproduce these cases, I'm seeing them popup in my automated error reports. If I could reproduce them it would be a hella lot easier :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your HTTP response headers include a `Content-Length` header that claims the JSON body is shorter then it really is.

Check if this is the case, find out where it is being added and correct it or remove it.

Comment: I have verified that the opposite sometimes happens, the content length is shorter than the Content-Length header. IE is lazy I guess :D. My solution is to force the server to send a Content-Length header. If JSON parsing fails I will compare the length of the string to the Content-Length header value and throw a 'transmission' error.